# Removing feature matched outliers within same image using RANSAC

Tags: python, image-processing, algorithms, homography

I'm a student working on a copy move forgery detection algorithm.

I have a forged image. By far I have,

1. Found keypoints and descriptors from the image
2. Matched the descriptors using 3 Nearest Neighbours algorithm and Lowe's Ratio technique.
   But there are still some outliers as shown in this image :

[image]

I have found out about the RANSAC algorithm. But in all the tutorials I see for opencv-python and skimage  , it is applied for 2 different images. I want to apply the RANSAC algorithm in the same image. I don't understand how to do so. Please guide me.

Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: Could you say something about the purpose?

Comment: @Royi I didn't get your question. As I have mentioned, this project is for detecting copy move forgery. In all the tutorials I have come across, RANSAC is applied on two different images. Here's an example: [feature matching opencv python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html). But I want to remove the outliers from the same image. Here's an example of outliers: [Feature Matching + Homography](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html)

Comment: Could you explain _Copy Move Forgery_?

Comment: Is it always the same object shifted you're looking for?